# Save files on golang server from client through websocket

Tags: go, websocket, backend

I want to save couple of files but the websocket keeps on restarting after creating a single file.  I get a websocket error

> websocket: close 1001 (going away)

When I remove the block of code of file saving, the for loop works, otherwise, the websocket restarts.

```
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error upgrading to WebSocket:", err)
    return
}
defer conn.Close()
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    questionaire:= questionaires[i].msg //a couple of questions to be sent to client
    if i == 0 {
        // send initial message to frontend
        sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaire)
    } else {
        messageType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err) // this line here logs the websocket error
            break
        }
        response = ""
        if messageType == websocket.BinaryMessage {

            // if this blocks of code here is removed, it works, otherwise restarts the websocket connection
            fileName := fmt.Sprintf("answer%d.wav", i)
            file, err := os.Create(fileName)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
              
            _, err = file.Write(msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            // til here
           // handle the saved file and call to speech to text api 
            
           response = "yes" //assumed the response is "yes"
        }
        switch response {
        case "yes":
            if i < len(questionaires) {
                sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaire)
            } else {
                sendServerMessageToClient(conn, "end")
                return
            }
        case "no":
            sendServerMessage(conn, "Exiting")
            return
        default:
            i--
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client

```
    ....
    <div id="statusLabel">Status: Waiting for server...</div><br><br>
    <audio controls id="audioPlayer"></audio><br><br>
    <button onclick="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
    <button onclick="stopRecording()">Stop Recording</button>

    <script>
        const statusLabel = document.getElementById('statusLabel');
        const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
        let mediaRecorder;
        let audioChunks = [];
        let ws;

        function startRecording() {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then((stream) => {
                    audioChunks = [];
                    statusLabel.textContent = "Status: Recording...";
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                        if (event.data.size > 0) {
                            audioChunks.push(event.data);
                            ws.send(event.data);
                        }
                    };
                    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                        audioPlayer.src = audioUrl;
                    };
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error));
        }

        function stopRecording() {
            statusLabel.textContent = "Stopped recording";
            ws.send("stop"); // Notify the server to stop recording
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        }

        // Establish WebSocket connection
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://golang-server.com/ws");

        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
            statusLabel.textContent = `${event.data}`;
        };

        ws.onclose = (event) => {
            statusLabel.textContent = "Connection closed";
        };
    </script>
 ...
```

Please let me know why the client stops it.

Comment: You can put your file saving code in go routine.

Comment: can you please provide a sample?

Comment: Is the message `websocket: close 1001 (going away)` reported on the server or the client?  If the message is reported on the server, then edit the question to show the code that prints that message.

Comment: @CeriseLimón edited the question and put a logger that prints that error msg.  This code here " messageType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err) // this line here logs the websocket error
            break
        }"

Comment: Based on the code provided, the error indicates that the client closed the connection.  There is insufficient information in the question to determine why the client closed the connection.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I just edited it and add the client side code.

Comment: `err != nil || err == io.EOF` io.EOF is never nil.  So this is the same as `err != nil`.

Comment: The server connection returns the error `websocket: close 1001 (going away)` when a 1001 close message is received from the client.  Web browsers send this close message when navigating away from the page or when echoing a 1001 close message from the server.  There is no server code that sends a close message, so it's likely that the client sent the message.  Debug by watching ws traffic in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: @CeriseLimón not quite sure why but if I remove that file saving, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue lies in the handling of the WebSocket connection and file saving within the loop. To resolve the problem, you can consider restructuring the code to better manage the WebSocket connection and file saving process. Here's a modified version:

```golang
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error upgrading to WebSocket:", err)
    return
}
defer conn.Close()

for i := 0; i < len(questionaires); i++ {
    questionaire := questionaires[i].msg

    if i == 0 {
        // send initial message to frontend
        sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaire)
    }

    messageType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    response := ""
    if messageType == websocket.BinaryMessage {
        // Save file only if it's a binary message
        fileName := fmt.Sprintf("answer%d.wav", i)
        file, err := os.Create(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        _, err = file.Write(msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        // Close the file after writing
        file.Close()

        // Handle the saved file and call the speech-to-text API
        // ...

        response = "yes" // Assume the response is "yes"
    }

    switch response {
    case "yes":
        if i+1 < len(questionaires) {
            sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaires[i+1].msg)
        } else {
            sendServerMessageToClient(conn, "end")
            return
        }
    case "no":
        sendServerMessage(conn, "Exiting")
        return
    default:
        // Handle other cases if needed
    }
}
```

This restructuring ensures that the file is saved within the loop but doesn't interfere with the WebSocket connection. Additionally, the loop now iterates over the questions array, eliminating the need for a separate variable (i) to keep track of the loop index.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your code and got the same error. I logged it in and it stops to this line here on next iteration
        "messageType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()"

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to save file

```
func FileSaveFunc(i int) {
    fileName := fmt.Sprintf("answer%d.wav", i)
    file, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    _, err = file.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    
}
```

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error upgrading to WebSocket:", err)
    return
}
defer conn.Close()
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    questionaire:= questionaires[i].msg //a couple of questions to be sent to client
    if i == 0 {
        // send initial message to frontend
        sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaire)
    } else {
        messageType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err) // this line here logs the websocket error
            break
        }
        response = ""
        if messageType == websocket.BinaryMessage {

            // if this blocks of code here is removed, it works, otherwise restarts the websocket connection
            go FileSaveFunc(i)
            // til here
           // handle the saved file and call to speech to text api 
            
           response = "yes" //assumed the response is "yes"
        }
        switch response {
        case "yes":
            if i < len(questionaires) {
                sendServerMessageToClient(conn, questionaire)
            } else {
                sendServerMessageToClient(conn, "end")
                return
            }
        case "no":
            sendServerMessage(conn, "Exiting")
            return
        default:
            i--
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also tried this but, still not works. However, if I remove that function it works